# Paint in JFrame not working (Java)

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, paint

So in class we are making a Java program. We are trying to use the paint(Graphics g) function in the JFrame. We have tried it in the past (weeks ago) and it used to work. But now it doesnt (or we made a mistake somewhere). We have also tried to use paintComponent(Graphics g) but nothing seems to work.
Here is our code:

```
public class MainAc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Class Paint");       
        JButton button = new JButton("Click for more");             
        frame.setSize(800, 600);    
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        button.setLayout(null);
        button.setLocation(100,100);
        button.setSize(200,100);
        frame.setVisible(true);     
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString("Hello", 200, 50);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what you're doing, is implementing a `paint` method inside your own `MainAc` class, not the `JFrame`.

Your `MainAc` class itself, should derive from the `JFrame`.

The code below should work. If you don't understand inheritance, you should look over your class notes, it'll be in there.

```
public class MainAc extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainAc();
    }
    
    public MainAc() {
        super("Class Paint");       
        JButton button = new JButton("Click for more");             
        setSize(800, 600);    
        add(button);
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        button.setLayout(null);
        button.setLocation(100,100);
        button.setSize(200,100);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawString("Hello", 200, 50);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Suggesting that the OP extend from a top level container AND failing to call super.paint is not doing the OP in favours and is an incredibly bad approach - IHMO

Comment: Fixed. There are obviously much better ways to do this. But the fact that OP doesn't appear to be particularly advanced, makes doing it the 'right' way a little less important.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work. Tryed to remove the button to see if the button overlaps but this just resulted in a weird Window.

Comment: *"But the fact that OP doesn't appear to be particularly advanced"* I would have thought that would have being the best reason to try and do it the best way possible - IMHO - to get the OP off on the right foot as it were

Comment: A fair point of view, of course you are free add a more in-depth answer if you wish.

Answer (score 12):

Your class doesn't extend from any `Component` capable of painting

Have a read through [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more ideas

You could do something like:

[image]

```
public class SimplePaint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimplePaint();
    }

    public SimplePaint() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new PaintPane());
                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    protected class PaintPane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            String text = "Look ma, no hands";
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
            int y = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
            g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
            g2d.dispose();


        }

    }

}
```

Where possible, you should avoid overriding top level container's `paint` methods, if for no other reason, they're not double buffered.

You should also try and extend from Swing based components for the same reason, as mixing heavy and lightweight components can cause issues with painting.

Answer (score 4):

As the code is, you are just defining a `paint` method in a class. The class extends `Object`, so you are not `overridding` paint on a `JComponent`.

Your class must extend any subclass of `Component` or `Component` itself in order to actually override `paint` or `paintComponent`. In your case, `MainAc` would extend `JFrame`.

Comment: *"must extend JComponet"* ... must it? What's wrong with JPanel?

Comment: Read the entire sentence "or a subclass of it".

Comment: Point, the meaning of communication is defined by the receiver. If that's all I picked it of it, imagine what the OP will pick out of it. It's nitty picky (sorry), but I would encourage you to re-word it slightly.  You "could", technically, extend from Component as well ;)

Comment: Cheers, I know I'm pain, but if we don't hold each other up to a high standard, what hopes is there for the posters ;) - You already earned a +1 from me to start with

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simplified version of Sticky's code that seems to work. I changed it to an extend JApplet and use the `init()` method instead of the `main()`.

```
public class JavaApplication51 extends JApplet {
    public  void something() {
       JButton button = new JButton("Click for more");             
        add(button);
        setLayout(null);
        button.setLayout(null);
        button.setLocation(100,100);
        button.setSize(101,20);
        setVisible(true); 
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawString("Hello", 200, 50);
    }

    public void init() {
        something();
    }
}
```