# Java PaintComponent: HowTo

Tags: java

So, I want to paint something on a Panel, using PaintComponent. But I want to do it in a Constructor. So, for example:

```
public class Interfata extends JPanel
{ 
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     g.setColor(Color.red);
     g.drawOval(500, 500, 50, 40);
  }

  public Interfata()
 {
         // code here
 }

  public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    Interfata i = new Interfata(); 
 }
```

The code should be like this model. The problem is that I don't know how to call the paintComponent method on a panel that create in the Constructor. ( Even though it may seem inefficient, I create the frame, panel and all the functions in the constructor, so, that I just have to instantiate that object in the main method). If I weren't clear enough, please do ask for any detail you may find suitable.

Edit: So to be more specific, this is how my Constructor looks like:

```
public Interfata()
{

    // main interface
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Queue");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1000, 450);
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (int) ((d.getWidth() - frame.getWidth()) / 2);
    int y = (int) ((d.getHeight() - frame.getHeight()) / 2);
    frame.setLocation(x, y);

    //simulation interface
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Simulare");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(900, 800);
    int x1 = (int) ((d.getWidth() - frame.getWidth()) / 2);
    int y1 = (int) ((d.getHeight() - frame.getHeight()) / 2);
    f.setLocation(x1, y1); 

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(null);


    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Intervalul minim de asteptare: ");
    JTextArea tf1 = new JTextArea();
    panel.add(l1);
    l1.setBounds(5,10,200,25);
    panel.add(tf1);
    tf1.setBounds(200,10,300,20);

    JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Intervalul maxim de asteptare: ");
    JTextArea tf2 = new JTextArea();
    panel.add(l2);
    l2.setBounds(5,50,200,25);
    panel.add(tf2);
    tf2.setBounds(200,50,300,20);

    JLabel l3 = new JLabel("Duarata minima pentru serviciu: ");
    JTextArea tf3 = new JTextArea();
    panel.add(l3);
    l3.setBounds(5,90,200,25);
    panel.add(tf3);
    tf3.setBounds(200,90,300,20);

    JLabel l4 = new JLabel("Durata maxima pentru serviciu: ");
    JTextArea tf4 = new JTextArea();
    panel.add(l4);
    l4.setBounds(5,130,200,25);
    panel.add(tf4);
    tf4.setBounds(200,130,300,20);

    JLabel l5 = new JLabel("Numarul de cozi: ");
    JTextArea tf5 = new JTextArea();
    panel.add(l5);
    l5.setBounds(5,170,100,25);
    panel.add(tf5);
    tf5.setBounds(200,170,300,20);

    JLabel l6 = new JLabel("Intervalul de simulare: ");
    JTextArea tf6 = new JTextArea();
    panel.add(l6);
    l6.setBounds(5,210,150,25);
    panel.add(tf6);
    tf6.setBounds(200,210,300,20);

    JButton b1 = new JButton("Simulare");
    panel.add(b1);
    b1.setBounds(700,100,100,35);
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            f.setVisible(true);

        }
    });

    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    f.setContentPane(panel1);
}
```

What I want to do exactly, is paint something in the panel of the NEW FRAME, or more specificaly, in the frame f.

Comment: Well `paintComponent` will be called by the w.e. so no need to call it. anywhere. you just simply need to override it and add some custom stuff like you already have. Atleast to my understanding.

Comment: Edited. I tried what you said, but it didn't paint anything.

Comment: You extend JPanel that is the one it will paint on... Not the newly created ones in your constructor

Comment: At the moment, you're only extending a JPanel here and then you're creating an anonymous JFrame to contain the panel in your constructor. You should probably just extend JFrame rather than JPanel. Then create JPanels that are children of your parent JFrame object and manipulate your draw operations between the frame and its panels accordingly.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136942/paint-in-jframe-not-working-java

Comment: I understand now. But how can I create panels that inherits that JFrame?